# Convert Persian date to English date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-8

i have a form that im sending data to my controller with that. One of my data is "report_date".

```
 <form action="{{ route('user.reports.store') }}" method="post" class="padding-30">
                @csrf
                <p class="box__title margin-bottom-15">دانش آموز</p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="کد دانش آموزی" class="text" name="user_code" value="{{ $user_intership->user_code }}">

                <p class="box__title margin-bottom-15">ترم دوره</p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="ترم دوره" class="text" name="intership_term_code" value="{{ $user_intership->intership_term_code }}">

                <p class="box__title margin-bottom-15">نام استاد</p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="نام استاد" class="text" name="teacher_code" value="{{ $user_intership->teacher_code }}">

                <p class="box__title margin-bottom-15">متن گزارش</p>
                <textarea id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="متن گزارش" class="text" name="report_text"></textarea>

                <p class="box__title margin-bottom-15">توضیحات</p>
                <textarea id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="توضیحات" class="text" name="description"></textarea>

                <p class="box__title margin-bottom-15">روز گزارش</p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="روز گزارش" class="text" name="report_day">

                <p class="box__title margin-bottom-15">تاریخ گزارش</p>
                <input type="text" class="text example1" id="date-time" name="report_date">

                <p class="box__title margin-bottom-15">مدرسه محل تحصیل</p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="محل تحصیل" class="text" name="school_code" value="{{ $user_intership->school_code }}">

                <p class="box__title margin-bottom-15"> محل کار آموزی</p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="محل کار آموزی" class="text" name="work_place_code" value="{{ $user_intership->work_place_code }}">

                <button class="btn btn-webamooz_net" type="submit">اضافه کردن</button>
            </form>
```

When i want to store my data in database my report_date input value is persian date. like this :

```
1400/05/05
```

But i want to convert it to gregorian date (English date) like this :

```
2021-7-27
```

Here is my controller :

```
public function store_report(Request $request)
{
    Intershipreport::create([
        'user_code' => $request->user_code,
        'teacher_code' => $request->teacher_code,
        'intership_term_code' => $request->intership_term_code,
        'report_day' => $request->report_day,
        'report_date' => $request->report_date,
        'report_text' => $request->report_text,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'school_code' => $request->school_code,
        'work_place_code' => $request->work_place_code,
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('user.reports-list')->with('success', 'گزارش شما با موفقیت ثبت شد');
}
```

I also Tried the Morilog package but i didint know how can i convert the date with that :)

Comment: In the package you mentioned, there is a `toCarbon` method. Surely that would help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert persian date to carbon instance using https://github.com/morilog/jalali package.

Install this package by running below command in your terminal

```
composer require morilog/jalali:3.*
```

Run below command to get persian date by giving its date format and convert it
to Carbon instance

```
$jDate = Jalalian::fromFormat('Y/m/d', '1400/05/05');
$carbon_instance = $jDate->toCarbon();
```

You need to cast the report_date in your `Intershipreport` model
to date and pass the carbon to it in `create` method.
Read more about date casting from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)

Intershipreport model

```
class Intershipreport
{
    // ...

    $date=[
        'report_date'
    ];
}
```

Then, easily create it like below:

```
Intershipreport::create([
        'user_code' => $request->user_code,
        'teacher_code' => $request->teacher_code,
        'intership_term_code' => $request->intership_term_code,
        'report_day' => $request->report_day,
        'report_date' => \Morilog\Jalali\Jalalian::Jalalian::fromFormat('Y/m/d', $request->report_date)->toCarbon(),
        'report_text' => $request->report_text,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'school_code' => $request->school_code,
        'work_place_code' => $request->work_place_code,
    ]);
```

Comment: Would you take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73527837/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-persian-at-laravel-migration