# How to show English DateTime to Persian one- PHP

Tags: php, datetime, farsi, persian-calendar

This is a table, it has a field named `register_date` which is automatically added by DB as a TimeStamp.
[image]

I want to show this field as a Persian DateTime. like this image below:

[image]

and here is my php piece of code:

```
<?php
    $q = "SELECT * from `tbl_registers2`";
    $result = $db->query($q);

    $row = 1;
    while ($fields = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <tr data-id="<?= $fields['id']; ?>">
            <td><?= $row++; ?></td>
            <td><?= $fields['first_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $fields['last_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $fields['mobile']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $fields['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $fields['register_date']; ?></td>
            <td><img class="delete" src="../assets/img/trash.png"></td>
            <td>
                <a href="edit.php?id=<?= $fields['id']; ?>">edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

how to do this?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think its clear. whats wrong?

Comment: This site is for posting your code and debugging details, and someone solves it for you.  It is not to write the code for you.  You have to show some effort.  When you are ready, edit your question and provide the details.  If they are sufficient, then your post will be flagged open again.

Comment: I think the question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73539996/7271221

Comment: @jspit the link you've provided was helpfull.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta could you please open this question? I've found the solution after 3 hours and want to add the answer

Comment: I can only vote to reopen it. which i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution myself after 3 hours.

the solution is to use the `IntlDateFormatter` class of PHP like this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');

$formatter=new IntlDateFormatter(
    'fa-IR@calender=persian',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'Asia/Tehran',
    IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL,
    "yyyy-MM-d H:m:s"
);


$q = "SELECT * from `tbl_registers2`";
    $result = $db->query($q);

    $row = 1;
    while ($fields = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dateTime = datetime::createfromformat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$fields['register_date']);
        ?>
        <tr data-id="<?= $fields['id']; ?>">
            <td><?= $row++; ?></td>
            <td><?= $fields['first_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $fields['last_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $fields['mobile']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $fields['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $formatter->format($dateTime); ?></td>
            <td><img class="delete" src="../assets/img/trash.png"></td>
            <td>
                <a href="edit.php?id=<?= $fields['id']; ?>">edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

`createfromformat` from `datetime` class is used to convert a plain date string which is read from database to a datetime object.
after all, `$formatter->format($dateTime);` shows the results.

to use `IntlDateFormatter` class, `extension=php_intl.dll` must be placed in the  `php.ini`.